How to configure SSH passwordless login authentication in local server
I hope you are well
I have 2 servers set up at home (a raspberry pi with Ubuntu server and a laptop with Ubuntu Desktop) they are configured with password login and I have configured and enabled SSH access for them (only for my local network)
I want to configure passwordless login (public-private key) via SSH and disable password authentication, up to this point I know how to configure all of the above but my real question is how do I access each of my servers physically?

I'm not sure I understand your question "how do I access each of my servers locally?" You access them locally via SSH using your private key, which was the whole point, no? Could you perhaps rephrase or elaborate?

By locally I mean the physical server

You plug in a keyboard and monitor, optionally a mouse or replace them with hardware that provides a remote console capability (iLO, iDRAC, IPMI). Linux also has an option for a serial console - so you could have a third device with serial connections to both / use minicom, but this does not provide BIOS/UEFI access.

I believe you have two options here.
If you disable password authentication in your sshd_config (PasswordAuthentication set to no) then you will be able to login to the system via SSH but only with a private key. You will still be able to access the system outside of SSH using the password. If the user is a sudoer, you will still be prompted for a password when trying to sudo via SSH, unless configured otherwise.
If you want to remove the password completely, you can with passwd -d which would mean that you can log into the system using a private key via SSH, but when physically accessing the system you will no longer be prompted for a password, which may be very unsafe.
